# Parse body query string post request

Tags: python, python-3.6

How can i parse a post request that is a query string, using tornado

`self.request.body` returns:

```
b'TS019a226e_id=3&TS019a226e_cr=08229a9b21ab2800b0db4f48c98582fa62bcf817398aca878ee020a55536d8214d5c12e3725e82299ced673b1228bc4a0807a58040894800d8da3ced7341bc4bf9ef220a13d88a982816db5fa9224c072cbec131c223af3b4efb82c5faf595647d1af0ef346c45d6214b4f9da8158aba08a4f3ce86dc7dfe161dc3b8f632c2e6&TS019a226e_76=0&TS019a226e_86=0&TS019a226e_md=1&TS019a226e_rf=0&TS019a226e_ct=0&TS019a226e_pd=0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tornado provides `escape` method ([documentation](http://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/latest/escape.html)). Use:

```
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

`escape` allows "escaping/unescaping HTML, JSON, URLs etc."

Comment: @AryehArmon give an error, please. What type of request do you deal (GET, POST, ...)?

Comment: this is a post request. the headers are application/x-www-form-urlencoded. and the response to self.request.body is a query string for some reason